# Can we move up the `rug()` and place it at a fixed point in an R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if there is a graphical parameter that could move up only the `rug()` and place it at exactly point "0" (as shown in the picture below; the bottom of the histogram)?

**Note:** I could play around with `line =` within the `rug()` call but it may not be as exact.

```
x = rnorm(1e2)   ;   y = dnorm(x)
hist( x, freq = F , ylim = c(-max(y), max(y)) )
rug( x )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rug.html), the `...` argument in `rug()` allows you to use further arguments passed to `axis()`. In this case use `pos`, for the position of the rug.

```
rug(x, pos = 0)
```